# Could not autowire. No beans of 'MongoOperations' type found. Error fix?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

`
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE6Jk.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5CEQ.png)
...
[Appication Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48qdR.png)

How to fix this error? How to create Bean class I already configured Mongodb in Property file...
Springboot and mongodb dependency already added i already checked data saved on database

Help me please..

```
help me fix this error guys...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something does not add up, and the info does not share how the pom is currently written. With the given details, the mongo configurations are established correctly on the java side

Try the below steps and see if it resolves the issue,

1. Check if spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb is added to pom.xml

   org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
2. Run a Maven clean install on the terminal to refresh the target folder

   mvn clean install

If it did not resolve the issue, can you commit this project to a GitHub repo and share the link?